# The logic behind this algorithm or how to teach this estimation

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to understand the logic behind the estimation of the calculation of the median from group data: (see this [link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html))

[image]

I understood the algorithm process, my question is about *the logic* behind this process. I'm going to teach some basic concepts in statistics to students with little mathematical background and I don't know how to teach this estimation to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should draw the cumulative frequency polygon and explain that the formula comes from a linear interpolation between the (known) cumulative frequencies of the bounds of the median group, which we can write:
$$\frac{n}{2}=cf_b+\frac{f_m}{w}(m-L)$$
From this we can deduce $m$.

Or course you don't have to tell them about *linear interpolation* but if you make a drawing it should be clear and visual. Moreover it'll give them a way to find the formula by themselves if they forget it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know where I can find a more detailed proof of this estimation? Thanks again.

Comment: @user42912: There are some difficulties in that we are dealing with discrete data, but basically if $x$ denotes the number of games and $y$ the corresponding cumulative frequency, we have the points $(10,9)$ and $(15,17)$ from the table. Then by assuming a constant rate of change and thus a linear growth between those two, we can find $(m,20/2)$ to be $$m=10+\frac{20/2-9}{17-9}\cdot (15-10)=10.625$$ I do not know why $L=11$ was used rather than $L=10$, however. Perhaps to fit discontinuity of the data better?

Comment: @user42912: Also see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) to see where the linear expression came from.